# Comparing bond lengths in metal carbonyls

Tags: bond, coordination-compounds, carbonyl-complexes

> Question:[image]

It's solution is given as:

[image]

Now I don't understand which d$\pi$ electrons have been considered here. For example, in $\ce{Fe(CO)_5}$, according to this, number of d$\pi$ electrons would be 4. I cannot see how it is 4. Secondly, is it the right method to compare the bond lengths?

I thought of this in terms of electron density, more is the electron density in the complex, stronger would be the metal ligand bond, hence weaker the carbon-oxygen bond, hence more the C-O bond length. But, since the atoms are different, I don't know if this idea would work in this case.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64999/will-the-bond-order-of-co-be-greater-in-its-existence-as-carbon-monoxide-or-in-m. There is a good answer to find bond order.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thanks for the link, but unfortunately I don't understand MOT in much detail, just the basics. For example, I am only familiar with $\ce{t_{2g}}$ and $\ce{e_g}$ orbitals. I have now got the part how the electron pairs are 4. It is because since CO is a strong field ligand, the configuration of $\ce{Fe}$ would be $\ce{[Ar] 3d^8}$. But still, my question remains, is this a correct method?

Comment: Each $\mathrm{d} \pi$ pair contributed to back bonding with $\ce{C#O}$ carbon so triple bond character get weaken (e.g., $\ce{Fe=C=O}$). That may be the theory behind this calculation. It is a crude method but works.

Comment: For the $Fe(CO)_{5}$ part, note that the formula is number of dπ electron $pairs$, hence $0.8$ indicates $4$ pairs of electrons or 8 electrons in total, as seen in the $3d^{8}$ configuration in $Fe$ in the presence of the strong field ligand $CO$. I have the same question in the second part however.

Comment: @Metaxylene Doesn't $Fe$ have a $3d^6$ configuration?

Comment: @LightYagami could you verify this method of finding the average CO bond length? I haven't seen it anywhere else personally. Is it from a reliable source?

Comment: @Ashish The question was asked in FIITJEE AITS, and this is the solution given by them, so I can't say it is from a verified source. Although it is a good method if we are indeed getting correct answers.