# Do Metal Carbonyl complexes exhibit multiple back donation at the same time?

Tags: bond, coordination-compounds

I came across a question which renewed one of my doubts that I had regarding bonding in metal Carbonyl complexes. According to me, metal should exhibit multiple back donation at the same time.

Everywhere on the web, I have only found metal carbonyl’s synergistic bonding in a single picture. But my doubt arises from the consideration from looking at the complete picture. According to me, In Metal Carbonyl complexes, the metal should exhibit multiple back donation to $\ce{ \pi^*}$ orbitals of Multiple Carbonyl Ligands according to the number of $\ce{d\pi}$ electron pairs present. I would like to explain this further through an example:

#### **Bonding in $\ce{Cr(CO)_6}$**

Now I do [know](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44591/metal-carbonyl-bonding?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the orbitals taking part in complex bonding are a blend of d,s and p but I only know CFT but will still be explaining my doubt while keeping that in my mind.

Here the metal, Chromium has $\ce{3d\pi}$ electron pairs which according to CFT are present in $\ce{d_{xy},d_{xz},d_{yz}}$ orbitals, I don’t know how it will be according to LFT but the *blended orbitals* still(maybe) should be oriented in that direction and that is what I simply wish to use. Since, $\ce{Cr(CO)_6}$ is octahedral, thus the back donation for only 3 Carbonyl Ligands is possible at the same time, **And this is where my question arises, that are there 3 back donations from $Cr$ at the same time or just a single back donation?**

At first, I thought that I could simply confirm multiple back donation thingy by comparing bond lengths of $Cr-C$ in $\ce{Cr(CO)_6}$ and some other compound say $\ce{Cr(CO)_3(NH_3)_3}$, if I was correct the bond length of $Cr-C$ would be shorter in the latter case, BUT I didn’t find any data regarding the latter compound, I tried to search here and there but no luck but I found [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149199/comparing-bond-lengths-in-metal-carbonyls) post on Chemistry SE, if I assume it is right then crudely,I can say that my idea is correct about the bonding in $\ce{Cr(CO)_6}$, **but I would like to have a further and deeper insight into this.**

***TL;DR*** Do Metal Carbonyl complexes exhibit multiple back donation at the same time or just a single back donation?

Comment: I find the question confusing. In BF3, the existence of the resonance hybrid means that all three pi interactions exist simultaneously, but they mutually weaken each other so the formal bond order on B is one total pi bond. So there's no difference between "multiple back donation at the same time" and "resonance hybrid"

Comment: @Andrew I mean to ask whether there exists 3 back donations as $Cr$ has $\ce{3d\pi}$ electron pairs or just 1. And Yes, I do think comparison with $\ce{BF_3}$ might be pointless.(I will be editing that out)

Comment: There are actually 12 "back donations" happening simultaneously, as each of the three off-axis d orbital interacts with all 4 ligands in its plane. Each ligand interacts via both of its orthogonal pi systems. For example, the CO located on the positive z axis interacts with dxz and dyz.

Comment: @Andrew As in $BF_3$ If one had to count the number of $B-F$ bonds, it would be 4(three sigma bonds and one back bond in resonance) That is what I wish to ask, In $Cr(CO)_6$ How many $Cr-C$ bonds are there. Also “For example, the CO located on the positive z axis interacts with dxz and dyz”, If that was the case then I don’t see how the correct representation would be M=C=O for such complexes.

Comment: With 3 filled d orbitals, you have three bonds worth of electrons, which divided by 6 ligands means a pi bond order of 0.5 (which is actually two 0.25 bonds, one in each of the two orthogonal pi systems on CO). But half bonds are a pain to draw, so M=C=O is a good way to represent that there are both sigma and pi interactions. No need to get too hung up on the exact bond order.